# C++ cannot convert ‘sender’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void* sending(void*)’

Tags: c++, pthreads, friend

I have startSending procedure and a friend function (`sending`) inside `sender` class. I want to call the friend function from a new thread, so I create a new thread inside `startSending` procedure.

```
class sender{
    public:
    void startSending();

    friend void* sending (void * callerobj);
}

void sender::startSending(){
    pthread_t tSending;
    pthread_create(&tSending, NULL, sending(*this), NULL);
    pthread_join(tSending, NULL);
}

void* sending (void * callerobj){
}
```

But I got this error

```
cannot convert ‘sender’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void* sending(void*)’
```

What is the correct way to call sending from pthread_create?

Comment: As far as I remember the method passed to pthread_create should be static. So something like  pthread_create(&tSending, NULL, sender::sending, NULL); declaring the sending as static.

Comment: @redobot Not really. It cannot be a non-static member function, but it can of course be a free function, as in the OP's case.

Comment: @Angew I didn't check the doc. But if he wants to use a class method this should be declared as static if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @redobot But he's *not* using a class member function.

Comment: @Angew that's right, I didn't see the sending declared outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pthread_create signature looks like this:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, //irrelevant
                   const pthread_attr_t *attr, //irrelevant
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), //the pointer to the function that is going to be called
                   void *arg); //the sole argument that will be passed to that function
```

So in your case, the *pointer* to `sending` must be passed as the third argument, and `this` (the argument that will be passed to `sending`) nees to be passed as the last argument:

```
pthread_create(&tSending, NULL, &sending, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation of `pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), you must pass in *the function* to be executed, not its invocation:

```
pthread_create(&tSending, NULL, &sending, this);
```

The argument with which the thread will call the function is passed as the 4th parameter to `pthread_create`, so in your case it's `this`.

And (while this is not actually necessary with most practical compilers on most common platforms) going strictly by the rules, since `pthread_create` is a C function, the function which you send to it should have C language linkage too:

```
extern "C" void* sending (void * callerobj){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_create(&tSending, NULL, sending, this);
```

OR

```
pthread_create(&tSending, NULL, &sending, this);
```